# php function not returning String containing Umlauts correctly

Tags: php, html

I have a php function that returns a string that contains German's Umlauts characters. ( Ex: für )
When the function is called, it returns the string as : f�r

I tried using :

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

at the top of my HTML page. Also used this meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

But both solutions didn't worked.

My php function looks like:

```
<?php 

function myfunc(){
return 'für';
}

?>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The string is not UTF-8 then... you _claim_ that it is UTF-8, but it isn't.

Comment: Make sure the PHP file is also saved in UTF8 not any Latin-15 or ISO format. An editor like VSCode or PHPStorm will show you in status bar (bottom right).

Comment: What is the encoding of your PHP source file? You need to encode this file in UTF-8.